# Checking if hash value has a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have a hash:

```
universityname = e.university
topuniversities = CSV.read('lib/assets/topuniversities.csv',{encoding: "UTF-8", headers:true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all})
hashed_topuniversities = topuniversities.map {|d| d.to_hash}

hashed_topuniversities.any? {|rank, name| name.split(' ').include?(universityname) }.each do |s|
  if s[:universityrank] <= 10
    new_score += 10
  elsif s[:universityrank] >= 11 && s[:universityrank] <= 25
    new_score += 5
  elsif s[:universityrank] >= 26 && s[:universityrank] <= 50
    new_score += 3
  elsif s[:universityrank] >= 51 && s[:universityrank] <= 100
    new_score += 2
  end
```

Basically what this is doing is looking at a hash and checking if the hash value contains a university name is an input.

For example the user input can be "Oxford University" and in the hash its stored as "Oxford". The User needs to type in as it stored in the hash to be able to be assigned a score, But I want it that if the user types in "oxford university" then the hash value "Oxford" should be selected and then go through.

Everything else in this works fine but the `.include?` does not work correctly, I still need to type the exact word.

Comment: Check out [Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: `Enumerable#any?` returns a boolean. `hashed_topuniversities.any? { ... }.each` is not going to work.

Comment: agreed. you'll want to do regex to match parts of the link. optionally you could use fuzzy matching to find the key that matches the best but that seems like a lot of overkill :P

Comment: Consider replacing your `if`'s with a `case` statement http://www.dotnetperls.com/case-ruby. It will help clean up your code. Also, you are missing the closing `end` to match the `do` following your `each` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your approach will work (in real-life, anyway). "University of Oxford" is an easy one--just look for the presence of the word, "Oxford". What about "University of Kansas"? Would you merely try to match "Kansas"? What about "Kansas State University"?

Also, some universities are are customarily referred to by well-know acronyms or shortened names, such as "LSE", "UCLA", "USC", "SUNY", "LSU", "RPI", "Penn State", "Georgia Tech", "Berkeley" and "Cal Tech". You also need to think about punctuation and "little words" (e.g., <sub><sup>"at", "the", "of"</sup></sub>) in university names (e.g., "University of California, Los Angeles").

For any serious application, I think you need to construct a list of all commonly-used names for each university and then require an exact match between those names and the given university name (after punctuation and little words have been removed). You can do that by modifying the hash `hashed_top_universities`, perhaps like this:

```
hashed_top_universities
  #=> { "University of California at Berkeley" => 
  #       { rank: 1, names: ["university california", "berkeley", "cal"] },
  #     "University of California at Los Angeles" =>
  #       { rank: 2, names: ["ucla"] },
  #     "University of Oxford" =>
  #       { rank: 3, names: ["oxford", "oxford university"] }
  #   }
```

Names of some universities contain non-ASCII characters, which is a further complication (that I will not address).

Here's how you might code it.

Given a university name, the first step is to construct a hash (`reverse_hash`) that maps university names to ranks. The names consist of the elements of the value of the key `:names` in the inner hashes in `hashed_top_universities`, together with the complete university names that comprise the keys in that hash, after they have been downcased and punctuation and "little words" have been removed.

```
PUNCTUATION = ",."
EXCLUSIONS  = %w| of for the at u |
SCORE = { 1=>10, 3=>7, 25=>5, 50=>3, 100=>2, Float::INFINITY=>0 }
```

```
reverse_hash = hashed_top_universities.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  (v[:names] + [simplify(k)]).each { |name| h[name] = v[:rank] } }
  #=> {"university california"=>1, "berkeley"=>1, "cal"=>1,
  #      "university california berkeley"=>1,
  #    "ucla"=>2, "university california los angeles"=>2,
  #    "oxford"=>3, "oxford university"=>3, "university oxford"=>3}

def simplify(str)
  str.downcase.delete(PUNCTUATION).
      gsub(/\b#{Regexp.union(EXCLUSIONS)}\b/,'').
      squeeze(' ')
end

def score(name, reverse_hash)
  rank = reverse_hash[simplify(name)]
  SCORE.find { |k,_| rank <= k }.last
end
```

Let's try it.

```
score("University of California at Berkeley", reverse_hash)
  #=> 10 
score("Cal", reverse_hash)
  #=> 10 
score("UCLA", reverse_hash)
  #=> 7 
score("Oxford", reverse_hash)
  #=> 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hashed_topuniversities = topuniversities.map &:to_hash

univ = hashed_topuniversities.detect do |rank, name|
  name.downcase.split(' ').include?(universityname.downcase)
end

new_score += case univ[:universityrank]
             when -Float::INFINITY..10 then 10
             when 11..25 then 5
             when 26..50 then 3
             when 50..100 then 2
             else 0
             end
```

Besides some code improvements in terms of being more idiomatic ruby, the main change is `downcase` called on both university name and user input. Now they are compared case insensitive.